# How to effectively use Galera Load Balancer with JDBC URL?

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, multi-master-replication

I am going to use Galera Load Balancer for Java JDBC URL for a multi-master Galera DB cluster. What are the correct states for that?

My JDBC URL is like this:

```
jdbc:mariadb:loadbalance//10.0.0.4:3306,10.0.0.5:3306/mydb?galeraAllowedState=4,2
```

Is it OK to use allowed states as 4 and 2? The recommended was 4, but the DB system also allows connections when it's state is 2 (donor).